triple-slash directives are not included when compiling package
I'm creating a npm package and want to reference where my types are, as so I have a folder typings, where my typings are located.
The structure is as follows:
├── typings/
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── foo.ts
│   ├── bar.ts

within foo.ts and bar.ts, I've declared modules:
declare module "@isimisi/foo" {
...
}

and within index.ts I'm using the triple-dash directive to include the modules, so I can export the typings in my package:
/// <reference path="./foo.ts" />
/// <reference path="./bar.ts" />

and withing my package.json I have:
"types": "build/typings/index.d.ts",
When I run tsc, the file build/typings/index.d.ts is completely empty, instead of including the triple-slash directives as they were in index.ts.
I've done this before, and have looked at older projects where I've done the exact same, and in these projects they build as expected, so I can't understand why it won't include the references in index.d.ts.
My tsconfig is as follows:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./build"
  ]
}

and using Typescript v5.1.6
Anyone similar problem that might have a solution to this?
